# How to access different lines in text files batch

Tags: url, text, batch-file, line

To clarify it First i'm making a url shortener script that use input.txt file as input and outputs as an output.txt where you can put unlimited links in the input.txt

This is what i got

```
@echo off
set /p firstline=<input.txt
echo %firstline%
for %%a in (%firstline%) DO (
set "text=http://adfoc.us/api/?key=c803bc5b2f2e8ad5ccb0166d4bc898ae^&url=%%a"
)
echo %text%>output.txt
```

example input.txt has 600 lines and i want to make them all in output.txt

Comment: I'm afraid it's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve, what the code that you've shown is meant to do or how it relates to your question. Can you try to clarify?

Comment: What is the issue? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you have an input.txt file that contain 600 lines with just the url part, and that you want to complete that lines with fixed http and key parts. If this is true, then the Batch file below do that:

```
@echo off
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) DO (
   echo http://adfoc.us/api/?key=c803bc5b2f2e8ad5ccb0166d4bc898ae^&url=%%a
)) >output.txt
```

Antonio

PS - If my answer is right, then you are NOT making an "url shortener script", but precisely the opposite thing! This script take an url and *enlarge* it by adding http and key parts, isn't it?

Comment: thanks, but that url is automatically creating short links btw thanks